# Automatically break/pause on code edit with "Edit and Continue" enabled

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017

**Is there any way to configure Visual Studio so that when I start typing something, the debugger automatically breaks instead of telling me that I need to break?**

I used to have "Edit and Continue" disabled but since my application is growing up in size therefore the compilation takes a long time. I found that having this option enabled is much more useful. But this message is very annoying. I usually forget to pause before starting Edit, and this windows pops up every time that I need to close. And if I pause, Visual Studio brings the code with current instruction which is usually not relevant to my changes. Placing a break point is also not very practical, especially with the code that is not executed in a loop.

Comment: Hi friend, what does the error message looks like? And do you mean you want a scenario that when starting typing something, the debugging stops automatically with the "Edit and Continue" enabled?!

Comment: Yes, with enabled and I don't have any error, it's just inconvenient behavior of IDE

Comment: In VS, actually the full name of this feature is [Edit and Continue Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue?view=vs-2017). It means if we enable the feature, all our changes will be recognized as a process of the debugging.

Comment: I understand that you want if you type some code for developing instead of debugging(Sometimes forget to pause), you want the debugger stops automatically. But for the debugger, since edit and continue debugging is enabled, he will recognize your change as a process of debugging, so it won't stop. But it's hard for the debugger to recognize if you want to write code or do edit and debug with the "edit and continue" enabled, so I'm afraid there is no setting in vs can configure "once typing, debugger stop"

Comment: It's by design of "Edit and Continue Debugging" feature, do hope you can understand. if I've misunderstood anything, please feel free to let me know. Thanks,

Comment: For now we have no the feature you want like Tools->options or Properties of Project and Solution can control this behavior. You can check if my answer is helpful, and if you post the feedback, you can share here and we can vote for you.

Comment: Almost :) I don't want to "Stop Debugging" but "Break All" so after I made change I can just "Continue" and see the changes immediately or hit "Restart" if changes are not possible to include in running application. I use the future both for debugging and for developing. I still don't understand why debugger can't just break and allow me to write instead of showing the "Changes are not allowed while code is running" message. Also the message is misleading. I've programmed for over a year with the EaCD disable before accidentally discovering that I actually can edit code of running application.

Comment: Yes, I've found several similar issues with the error message "Changes are not allowed while code is running". And always we have to uncheck "Edit and continue", to get it solved. I'll vote for your idea and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to configure Visual Studio so that when I start
>   typing something, the debugger automatically breaks instead of telling
>   me that I need to break?

For now, we have no such feature in VS, whether we enable or disable the "Edit and Continue", if we start typing something, the debugger won't stop automatically.
And I think your request deserves a trial. If we have the feature you want, the behavior can be more convenient. So I support that you can post this "adding feature" in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).

> And the "Edit and Continue" feature is not only [Edit and Continue
>   Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue?view=vs-2017).

With this feature enabled, it not only help us debug, also it can save the changes you type even after stop the debugging. So we can use this feature to do the "start typing sth" when forget to pause the debugger.

Cause all our changes will be saved to code editor.Of course, there might be other inconvenient behavior with the feature, you can post your feedback to DC(Now our user voice of VS is most in Developer Community) to get more help.Do hope you can understand.

Comment: Thanks, I don't believe they going to do it but I posted suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/498357/automatically-breakpause-on-code-edit-with-edit-an.html)